# How to use ractivejs partials with a variable name?

Tags: template-engine, ractivejs

I'm using ractivejs to render html both on the server and on the client. I would like to have one index page as an ractivejs instance, in which page templates can be rendered, based on a variable name, like:

```
this.ractive = new Ractive({
  template: _GLOBAL.templates.index,
  partials: _GLOBAL.templates,
  data: {
    context: context,
    getPage: function () {
      /** Should return rendered partial, or something that will end up as {{> myPartialName}} in index */
      return '> home';
    }
  }
})
```

Is this currently possible with ractivejs?

Answer (score 4):

At present, partials don't work like that - whatever the value of `ractive.partials.myPartialName` is when the instance is created is what will get rendered in place of `{{>myPartialName}}` .

Changing partials post-render is something that may be added to a future version, as it's come up more than once.

But for the time being your best bet, if you're using a single instance for multiple 'pages', is probably something like this:

```
{{# page === 'home' }}
  {{>home}}
{{/ page === 'home' }}

{{# page === 'admin' }}
  {{>admin}}
{{/ page === 'admin' }}

{{# page === 'whatever' }}
  {{>whatever}}
{{/ page === 'whatever' }}
```

Then switching between pages would happen like so:

```
ractive.set( 'page', 'home' );

// or, if there were transitions involved - e.g. one page flies out,
// the other flies in
ractive.set( 'page', null, function () {
  ractive.set( 'page', home );
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply! The first option is a bit problematic for me, since i have to hardcode the amount of pages.

Comment: @Rich - didn't it used to be that you could set `this.template` in `beforeInit`? It doesn't work now, but maybe I am imagining it ever worked...

Comment: @martypdx good question, I can't remember. It's the kind of thing that could have changed without anyone noticing, because (if it did work) it was a side-effect rather than a deliberate feature, and there would have been no tests. I can see how it could be useful though...

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to create the main template as a component:

```
<script type='text/ractive' id="main">
   <h1>Main Page</h1>
     {{>content}}
   <div> footer </div>
</script>
```

Then use that to wrap each page template:

```
<script type='text/ractive' id="page1">
    <main>
        <p>I am page 1</p>
    </main>
</script>
```

The you can just render the page template:

```
new Ractive({
    template: template //'#page1', '#page2, etc
}).toHTML()
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/3yjMj/

Answer (score 0):

I only need it to work like that serverside, so this seems to work ok for me as well:

```
res(peer.getSnapshot(_GLOBAL.templates.home, context))

getSnapshot: function(template, context) {
    var Ractive = require('ractive')
    /** Inject a page template in the main template */
    var pageRactive = new Ractive({template: template, data: context})
    this.ractive = new Ractive({
      template: _GLOBAL.templates.index,
      partials: _GLOBAL.templates,
      data: {
        context: context,
        getPage: function () {
          return pageRactive.toHTML()
        }
      }
    })
    return this.ractive.toHTML({})
  }
}


<body>
  {{{getPage()}}}
</body>
```